# Cloud tab under Agents missing - Team City

Tags: build, continuous-integration, devops, teamcity, continuous-deployment

I'm looking to set up cloud based scalable build with Team city on EC2 as per below article.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/setting-up-teamcity-for-amazon-ec2.html

I have System Administrator privileges for root projects but I'm unable to see the Cloud tab under the Agents page.

[Cloud tab under Agents missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMfM6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. The Cloud Tab under agents is only visible once you have configured the Cloud profiles for your projects.